# How to create CI/CD pipeline for NextJS app with .yml and gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, next.js, yaml, devops, gitlab-ci

I followed a tutorial on youtube [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJ63nXg-LvQ&t=1349s) to create a ci/cd pipeline for deployment on netlify.
The builds are successful but the deploy shows a 404 page.
[Link to deployed site](https://619e1c3e43402f1492b31cc9--sharp-shaw-afd5ec.netlify.app/)

I'm posting the yml commands below

```
stages:
  - lint
  - build
  - deploy
lint project:
  stage: lint
  image: node:15
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run lint
build project:
  stage: build
  image: node:15
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - .next
netlify:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:15
  script:
    - npm set prefix ~/.npm; path+=$HOME/.npm/bin
    - path+=./node_modules/.bin
    - npm install -g netlify-cli
    - netlify deploy --dir=.next --prod
```

I'm trying to create a Next JS boilerplate to be used in my future projects & Through CI/CD pipeline i'm looking for automated deployment. Any help or link to resources would be appreciated.